# Preserve return code from python script in Jenkins when used in a bash pipe

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, jenkins

Consider this:

```
$ cat test.py 
import sys
print "Doing something ..."
sys.exit(1)

$ python test.py
Doing something ...
$ echo $?
1

$ python test.py | tee log # used in Jenkins, but I need to capture rc of 1 as well
Doing something ...
$ echo $?
0
```

As you can see I am unable to capture the return code of 1 from the python script if I pipe the output to tee. Is there a way I can accomplish this ? This code is in Build->execute shell section in Jenkins.

Since I am unable to capture the rc of 1 the commands following the line continue to get executed, which I don't want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding  "Since I am unable to capture the rc of 1 the commands following the line continue to get executed", you can add `set -o errexit` and `set -o pipefail` to the start of your script, it will then terminate directly if you get an error (even inside a piped command). [Here a good resource with a more in-depth explanation.](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts/#idm5413512)

Answer (score 3):

In `bash` you can use the `PIPESTATUS` array to get the exit status of each command in a pipeline:

```
python test.py | tee log
echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```